# Connection lost during mqtt connection with rabbit mq server

Tags: mqtt

Actually i am using rabbit mq server and mosquitto mqtt client for the connection 
but after sometime server is disconnecting from the client 
and the error in not traceable.

Comment: That is not a question, it's more of a statement

Answer (score 0):

You should check the rabbitmq log (and log [configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)) and also test with different keep alive values.

Comment: can you tell me what is "UL" in 1000UL in mqtt. yes you are right according to keep alive values mqtt connection is responding but how much value can we set for continuing the connection so that there will be no disconnection.

Comment: UL is and Unsigned Long in C++ not MQTT.
Keep Alive time frame is used for the Client to know that if that period has passed without any message exchange will send a PINGREQ to the Broker and if the Client doesn't obtains the PINGRESP, then will try to reconnect.